# qt quick drag & drop item shakes when dragging

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml

I've got QML ListView with draggable items. And when I take item and move mouse sometimes(pretty often) item shakes back to initial position then to actual position back etc.
It's happend with Qt 5.5.1 on Linux and Windows.
Below is example code with problem. Try drag items from left right to left and see output log. Sometimes its a lot of output about enter/leave drop area.

```
    import QtQuick 2.5
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

    Window {
        visible: true
        width: Screen.width
        height: Screen.height
        property int num:150
        Row{
            anchors.fill: parent
            ColumnLayout{
                id:col1
                width: parent.width/2
                height: parent.height
                DropArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onEntered: {
                        console.log("entered:"+drag.source)
                    }
                    onExited: {
                        console.log("exited:"+drag.source)
                    }

        }
                ListView{
                    spacing: 2
                    model:num
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    delegate: Rectangle{
                        width: parent.width/2
                        height: width
                        color:"green"
                    }

        }
            }
            ColumnLayout{
                id:col2
                width: parent.width/2
                height: parent.height

        ListView{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    spacing: 2
                    model:num
                    delegate: Rectangle{
                        id:restItem
                        property point beginDrag
                        property int maxDragX: 96
                        width: parent.width/2
                        height: width
                        color:"red"
                        Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
                        MouseArea {
                            id: mouseArea
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            drag{
                                target: restItem
                                axis: Drag.XAxis
                                smoothed: true
                                threshold: width/3
                                maximumX: 0
                                minimumX: -maxDragX

                    }
                            preventStealing: true
                            onPressed: {
                                restItem.beginDrag = Qt.point(restItem.x, restItem.y);
                            }
                            onReleased: {
                                backAnimX.from = restItem.x;
                                backAnimX.to = beginDrag.x;
                                backAnimY.from = restItem.y;
                                backAnimY.to = beginDrag.y;
                                backAnim.start()
                            }
                        }
                        ParallelAnimation {
                            id: backAnim
                            alwaysRunToEnd: true
                            running: false
                            SpringAnimation { id: backAnimX; target: restItem; property: "x"; duration: 500; spring: 2; damping: 0.2 }
                            SpringAnimation { id: backAnimY; target: restItem; property: "y"; duration: 500; spring: 2; damping: 0.2 }
                        }
                    }

        }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was working with your code, and I only see this behaviour if I click and try to move the item when this one is still moving. If the item finishes its movement or animation, then I don't observe the issue you explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a comment, but I would like to share with you also an answer with a possible solution.

In this case, you could enable or disable the `MouseArea` to avoid the problem.

The idea is to disable the MouseArea in `onPressed` slot and to enable it when the animation stops and it is called the `onStopped` slot.

```
...

                delegate: Rectangle{
                    id:restItem
                    property point beginDrag
                    property int maxDragX: 96
                    width: parent.width/2
                    height: width
                    color:"red"
                    Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
                    MouseArea {
                        id: mouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag{
                            target: restItem
                            axis: Drag.XAxis
                            smoothed: true
                            threshold: width/3
                            maximumX: 0
                            minimumX: -maxDragX

                        }
                        preventStealing: true
                        onPressed: {
                            mouseArea.enabled = false;
                            restItem.beginDrag = Qt.point(restItem.x, restItem.y);
                        }
                        onReleased: {
                            backAnimX.from = restItem.x;
                            backAnimX.to = beginDrag.x;
                            backAnimY.from = restItem.y;
                            backAnimY.to = beginDrag.y;
                            backAnim.start()
                        }
                    }
                    ParallelAnimation {
                        id: backAnim
                        alwaysRunToEnd: true
                        running: false
                        SpringAnimation { id: backAnimX; target: restItem; property: "x"; duration: 500; spring: 2; damping: 0.2 }
                        SpringAnimation { id: backAnimY; target: restItem; property: "y"; duration: 500; spring: 2; damping: 0.2 }
                        onStopped: {
                            mouseArea.enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
...
```